# Ansible: Copying different files to different guests for use with the same role

Tags: ansible

I have a role, let's call it apache2. The role installs apache2 and all of its dependencies.

Now I have two machines, let's call them M1 and M2. Both M1 and M2 need to have apache2 installed. However, each of them needs their own set of files installed into the web root. So M1.yml looks like:

```
---
- hosts: M1
    - role: apache2
```

M2.yml looks like:

```
---
- hosts: M2
    - role: apache2
```

Obviously I can't just put the files into the role's `files` directory, as they are different for each. Options of which I am aware:

1. Create a `post_tasks` section for each playbook that copies over the necessary files and configures the server.
2. Create a `copy_files` role that takes the files as a variable

The reason I don't like #1 is because I might have a bunch of similar roles (apache2, nginx, ftp, etc.) each of which requires installation and files to be copied over. I'd like to keep each "together", meaning that the "install apache2" and "copy apache2 files to guest" tasks are both specified near each other in the file.

The reason I don't like #2 is because it seems heavyweight to basically just wrap a task as a role.

Is there another option I'm not thinking of? And of the available options, which is considered best practice?

Answer (score 1):

Another approach that I found uses the `include_role` directive. So instead of the playbook being:

```
---
- hosts: M2
  - roles:
    - role: apache2
```

It becomes:

```
---
- hosts: M2
  - tasks:
    - include_role: apache2
```

Then I can add tasks directly after that apache2 task that configure apache2:

```
---
- hosts: M2
  - tasks:
    - include_role: apache2

    - copy:
        # etc
```